# SSIS OLE DB Source not returning rows with parameterized query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am creating an SSIS package. It uses an OLE DB Source to pull data. When I run the query, it works fine. When I try to insert a parameter into the query, it doesn't return any rows. My query works fine in SSMS without the parameter. My query is as follows:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM SQL_AP_INVOICES_ALL 
WHERE LAST_UPDATE_DATE >= Convert(varchar(8), ?, 112)
```

The parameter is in the form of `YYYYMMDD`. I'm fairly new to SSIS and don't know how to debug the query. I will also add that the data rows are returned if I preview the data.

The following screenshot shows my parameter configuration:

[image: Parameters]

If you need any further information that I have not provided, I will answer.

Comment: You can use SQL profiler or XEvent Profiler if you're using a new version of SSMS, i think the problem on how you pass the parameter, can you add how you do the parameter mapping.

Comment: When I review in XEvent Profiler, I can see that the parameter is passed in the preview. However, when I try to run the query I get an undefined parameter. Thank you, you have been very helpful.